# Why does this basic thread program fail with Clang but pass in g++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this simple program that works with threads. In Clang I get a bunch of confusing irrelevant errors. Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

int main()
{
   std::packaged_task<int()> task([] { return 1; });
   std::future<int> result = task.get_future();

   task();

   std::cout << "Result was: " << result.get();
}
```

Errors:

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'duration' (aka '`std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1, 1000000> >`')
>                 : _*d(*_t.time_since_epoch())
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization `'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1, 1000000> > >::time_point<std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >'` requested here

There's a lot more, but you can see it in [this link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243290) of the program. Oddly, it compiles fine in g++ 4.7.3 and 4.6.3. Why is this only happening in Clang?

**Update:** As David pointed out, it seems only to be failing when I include the `<future>` header.

Comment: What version of clang?

Comment: @mkb 3.2, the latest that Liveworkspace provides.

Comment: You might need `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @BrettHale That suppresses the previous errors, but then I get `error: iostream file not found`.

Comment: It seems to be failing only when you include the `<future>` header.

Comment: Works fine for a modern clang here. (Apple LLVM 4.21). I'm assuming you're using -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm just using `-std=c++11` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a documented bug in clang/libstdc++.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=666539

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12893

From Clang's [status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html):

> Clang's C++11 mode can be used with libc++ or with gcc's libstdc++, but patches are needed to make libstdc++-4.4 work with Clang in C++11 mode. Patches are also needed to make libstdc++-4.6, and libstdc++-4.7 work with Clang releases prior to version 3.2 in C++11 mode.

Comment: It looks like a bug in libstdc++, not clang.

Comment: @Omnifarious, it's not a "bug" in libstdc++ because using those headers with Clang is not documented as a feature or something that's supposed to work :P

Answer (score 1):

This is an incompatibility between libstdc++ and clang. If you were to build against libstdc++ 4.8.0, this problem goes away.

```
[11:43am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/llvm/3.2/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++11 -gcc-toolchain /opt/gcc/4.8.0 se.cc |& wc -l
0
[11:43am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/llvm/3.2/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++11 -gcc-toolchain /opt/gcc/4.7.2 se.cc |& wc -l
21
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening with clang 3.2, it's not [bug 12893](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12893) (which was fixed in clang 3.2).

It is more likely to be [this bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15517), which is really a bug in libstdc++ 4.7: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53841